# How to import a PHP project from WAMP to MAMP?

Tags: wamp, mamp, wampserver

All,

I'm moving a PHP project from a Windows machine where I was using WampServer to a MacBook where I'm running MAMP.

My question is, where should I copy my php files on the Mac?

Comment: `where should I copy my php files on the Mac?` What does the [MAMP documentation](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/) have to say about this?

Comment: @admdrew - thanks for that. The stack I installed is from Bitnami, but maybe that was a mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webroot for MAMP is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`

So try putting all your php files there and if you have MAMP turned on, you should be able to point your browser to `http://localhost` and see them.